# How to stop ordering CONCAT REGEXP MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have the following code which force me to order values from lowest to highest.

```
$values = '4|2|7|1|20';

$test = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT id FROM user WHERE (CONCAT(',', id, ',') REGEXP ',($values),')");

foreach ($test as $test_as) {
  echo $test_as['id'].',';
}

// Output:
1,2,4,7,20

// Should be same as string values:
4,2,7,1,20
```

How I can stop ordering it by default and make by `values` order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id,4,2,7,1,20);
```

To your SELECT.

You still should use prepared stetement when you are4 testing.